# Extjs scroll two panels in parallel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two panel and both have `autoScroll: true`. I want them to scroll in parallel; that is, scroll one, the other should automatically scroll as well.
My Code:

```
Ext.define('CompareDailog', {

    extend      : 'Ext.window.Window',
    width       : '100%',
    height      : '100%',
    resizable   : true,
    closeAction : 'destroy',
    editMode    : false,
    padding     : '1 1 1 1',

    layout      : {
        type        : 'border',
        align       : 'left',
        padding     : '5 5 5 5'
    },

    items       : [{
        xtype       : 'panel',
        id          : 'originalDocument',
        title       : 'Original Document',
        width       : '50%',
        height      : '100%',
        region      : 'west',
        autoScroll  : true
    }, {
        xtype       : 'panel',
        id          : 'modifiedDocument',
        title       : 'Modified Document',
        width       : '50%',
        height      : '100%',
        region      : 'east',
        autoScroll  : true
    }],

    buttons     : [{
        text        : 'Cancel',
        handler     : function() {
            this.up('window').close();
            return;
        }
    }]
});
```

I search but not found any scroll listener or move scroll to anty specific position. nay help is appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried this myself but it looks like you need to use the scrollBy method.  

[link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-scrollBy)

You could make a function to pass the other grid panel the scroll coordinates and it would have this appearance.

Look here for an example of passing a scroll bar coordinance:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010108/extjs-4-0-7-scrollto-scrolls-but-doesnt-move-scroll-bar-slider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the another aspect for `Ext.Panel` component. Basically, you can set scrollbar position of an element by `body.dom` property.

[ExtJS - Synchronize Two Panel Scrollbars](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/52o)

```
var panelOne = Ext.getCmp('originalDocument');
var panelTwo = Ext.getCmp('modifiedDocument');

panelOne.body.on('scroll', function(e) {
    panelTwo.body.dom.scrollTop = panelOne.body.getScrollTop();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is fiddle. If you have any problem, let me know.

[Synchronize Two Grid with Scroll](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/51h)

Comment: The logic is mostly the same. Modify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an old post but I want to share my part of answer. See, when adding synching scrollbars, problem is the mousewheel scrolling is somewhat slow.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CSwAH/).

So, what I've come up with is to add a delay to the event:

```
var panelOne = Ext.getCmp('originalDocument');
var panelTwo = Ext.getCmp('modifiedDocument');

panelOne.body.on('scroll', function(e) {
    panelTwo.body.dom.scrollTop = panelOne.body.getScrollTop();
}, panelOne.body, {delay: 50 }); //delay 50 seems to fine to me. adjust if you must
```